# Does the Enhanced Ecommerce data layer need to be sent on non-ecommerce pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to add Google Analytics.

As the title suggests, do I need to Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features for all pages, or should I create a tag that is triggered on actual ecommerce pages and enable it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the EE dataLayer does not need to be on all pages. Assuming your page view tag is enabled to track EE data via the dataLayer, it will only track whatever you push to it, so no EE data pushed means no EE data in GA.